# Rewrite whole file and add to specific line

Tags: python

Hello I am making a scoreboard program that checks whether the user's name is in a text file, if it does appear, it would take the line and adds his new score onto that line, but if the name isn't in the text file, it would write on a new line, his name, then score.

```
def check(a):
    datafile = open("Class%d.txt"%(group))
    for line in datafile:
        if (a) in line:
            return True
    return False
name = input("What is your name? : ").lower().capitalize()
r = open("Class%d.txt"%(group),"a+")
g = open ("Class%d.txt"%(group), 'w')
for line in r:
    if check(name) == True:
            g.write(line + ("\t") + str(score) + ("\n"))
    else:
            g.write(line)
            g.write(("\n") + str(name) + ("\t") + str(score))
else:
    r.write(("\n") + str(name) + ("\t") + str(score))
r.close()
g.close()
```

I was suggested to rewrite my file (the file would be small so I shouldn't be affected by the file size being too big), I want it so that if the name is in the line, it would still rewrite the line but with some additions, and if the name specified isn't in the line, the line would just be rewritten as is.
I would prefer to not use any modules not built into python. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

```
name = 'Peter'
new_score = '2700'
with file('/tmp/test2', 'r+') as datafile:
    lines = datafile.readlines()
    found=False
    for i in xrange(len(lines)):
        fields = lines[i][:-1].split(' ')
        if name == fields[0]:
            fields[1] = new_score
            lines[i] = ' '.join(fields)+'\n'
            found=True
            break
    if not found:
        lines.append('%s %s\n' % (name, new_score))
    datafile.seek(0)
    datafile.writelines(lines)
    datafile.truncate()
```

Comment: file.writelines() doesn't add newlines ('\n'). So you should do it yourself when adding new name.  Yet my example split lines on fields so it looks for exact name matching (without re) and not confusing by similar names like Alex and Alexander.

Answer (score 0):

You algorythm is bad : you first iterate the file once to see if the name is there, but instead of simply searching the name in the line, your `check` function searches it in the while file.

Worse, your are opening the file twice, once in `a+` and immediately after (even before reading it) you truncate it to 0 size by opening it in `w` mode ...

As you say your file is small, you could read everything in memory, replace the line containing the name if it exists or add a new one, and then write everything back :

name = input("What is your name? : ").lower().capitalize()

```
r = open("Class%d.txt"%(group),"r")
lines = r.readlines()
r.close()
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if name in line:
        lines[i] = name + "\t" + str(score)
        break
else:
    lines.append(name + "\t" + str(score))
w = open(("Class%d.txt"%(group),"w")
w.writelines(lines)
w.close()
```

You could also open in r+ mode, rewind the file with `r.seek(0)` and truncate it at the end.